# Saving variables in the url

Tags: javascript, url, save

I was thinking how I could save multiple variables in the URL of the website using java script, but I searched all over the web and I could not find a single way of how to do it.

If any of you could help me that would be great!

Comment: https://github.com/SLaks/PageOptions

Comment: Perhaps if you describe what problem you're really trying to solve rather than the solution you're pursuing, we could help you better.  My wild guess would be that cookies or LocalStorage are what you need, but I'm not really sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jquery. It has functions which can use easily. Go through following tutorial :

[Url encode decode tutorial](http://www.jquery4u.com/snippets/jquery-decode-url-string/)